# Making tags visible when using the Tumblr theme 101 by jaredbishop

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-tags

I am using the theme 101 by jarredbishop and I noticed that the tags don't show. I tried using the

```
{block:HasTags}
   {block:Tags}
      <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
   {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
{/block:Posts}
```

method but the tags appear at the top of the page instead of under the corresponding post.

Can anyone help me, please?